# How does upgrading my traps work?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Since the Update 5.64 for Clash of Clans, you can now upgrade your traps (bombs, etc).   If I were to upgrade a trap to level 2 and then an opponent sets off that trap, do I have to upgrade it again later or does it perminenatly stay at level 2 but then just cost more to re-arm that trap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though me doing quite well in the game when traps go off they remain in the same postion and same level. It will cost more gold to re-arm them but they do retain there level after detonation. 
Here is a link to the [Wiki](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Traps) that states:

> Upgrade levels don't disappear when traps are triggered.